# Third level Options page in Visual Studio addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

In creating [custom options page section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b389wd38.aspx), the help shows for 2nd level option page and says there is no support for 3rd level option page.

But there must be a way to do that, given that, so many option pages already do that.

How can we implement the 3rd level option page (rough idea below)

```
<ToolsOptionsPage>
        <Category Name="Environment">
            <SubCategory Name="My Tools Options Page Parent">
            <SubCategory Name="My Tools Options Page">
                <Assembly><dll location></Assembly>
                <FullClassName>ToolsOptionsLibrary.UserControl1
                </FullClassName>
            </SubCategory>
            </SubCategory>
        </Category>
    </ToolsOptionsPage>
```

So as to get options page as:
Options-> Environment -> My Tools Options Page Parent -> My Tools Options Page

Comment: maybe the functionality you're looking for can be achieved by adding a button on the Option page that pops up another form?

Comment: unfortunately that would not be conventional. thanks